# .NET compilation without JIT possible?

Tags: .net, compilation, jit

Is it possible to compile a .cs directly in x86 code ?
I mean, I want to observe what happened with IDA Pro, so I didn't want IL code but asm code.

Thanks

Comment: Why? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to observe the internals

Comment: So I need x86 code, no IL code..
I can do it with windbg, but I really prefer IDA...

Comment: The internals of what? The underlying .NET code? Your own code? And what do you hope to achieve by observing those internals?

Comment: I want to see how are done the objects in memory, etc...

Comment: @Thomas: That's *what* you want to do, but it doesn't say *why* you want to do it or what you think you can do with this information. If you just want to know how a .NET VM is supposed to act, you'd be better off reading the spec.

Comment: But I don't find the spec, only rotor but it's really, really big...

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [Ngen.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Comment: I have try a :

ngen.exe /install myprogram.exe

But next with IDA, I have IL code, no x86.. :(

Comment: Ngen will install the native image typically in your Windows directory under /assembly/NativeImages or something like that. Are you looking at your program there? 

Another option to view the assembly that I prefer is to enable address-level debugging in your Visual Studio debugging options and use the provided debug windows.

Comment: Yes I have looked in WINDOWS\assembly\nativeimages... but next, it's IL code. I think it's not possible, or more simple to find the spec if I want to study the internals.

Answer (score 1):

IDA won't load native parts from NGEN'd assemblies, unfortunately. The only way I found was to use the Visual Studio debugger.

If you're not interested specifically in the Microsoft .NET framework internals, but in any other JIT as well, you can play with mono --aot, which produces normal PE or ELF executables (and even the readable assembler sources).